# How to access the Dahl weapon chest in the Outlands Canyon, behind the electric fence?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

In ***Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel***, in the Outlands Canyon (which you can access about 25% through the game), there is a Dahl weapon chest behind an electric fence. How can I access it?

Normally, there is a switch nearby that I have to throw at a fusebox to disable the fence. But I can't find one.

What I *did* find was a switch on the ground, on which I ground slam it to flip it from green to red. (To get a high enough height to ground slam this switch, I found a destroyable rock, which revealed an air geyser which I used.) Above the electric fence entrance, there are three orbs, all in red. Ground slamming that ground switch changes the first orb to green. But that's it.

I've been trying to find other ground switches but I can't.

Anyone know how to access this chest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made a video:

there's three touchplates. One by the air dome generator by the terra madre treasure quest, one by the garbage where you search for the map and fight the thresher, and that one thing there.

Comment: Thanks. That looks pretty tricky so I wouldn't have been able to figure it out myself, that's for sure.

Comment: Please include a description of the video so if, for any reason, it becomes unavailable, your answer is still helpful.

Comment: @Batophobia like now when the video is no longer available.....

Answer (score 11):

There are three touchplates that you have to slam within a time limit.

[image: map with markers]

1. By the building between the Garage and O2 in the northeast of the electric fence.
2. By the O2 generator southeast of the first generator.
3. Below the slope with the electric fence.

[image: in-game screenshots of locations]

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the map with highlights. I find that way more useful than a video - although the video is great if I still can't find them once I'm at the way points.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found out how to do it! I could not find anything else online, so I made a quick video explaining where they are. First video I have made so wont be to good, but should help!

There's three touchplates. One by the air dome generator by the terra madre treasure quest, one by the garbage where you search for the map and fight the thresher, and that one thing there.

Answer (score 0):

It's a timed thing. There are areas mostly next to the "O2" places you see on the map, and you can see above where they are. You don't have to use a stingray, I didn't, you just need to be quick. What's in there isn't worth it anyways, just green weapon(s). Waste of time unless you are going to sell, are level 10 and just need some green weapons, or are planning to grind.